# tengo problemas con "echo" vacio en php

Tags: php, php7

les comento, tengo un formulario en donde solamente se cargan direcciones de emails

La idea es que cuando un usuario ingrese por ejemplo pepito@pepito.com
la pagina le diga, "usted ingreso pepito@pepito.com"
el problema que tengo con el echo es que al entrar a la pagina, me muestra de entrada "usted ingreso" , como puedo eliminar eso?

```
<?php echo "usted ingreso $email"; ?>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Puedes hacer el `echo` sólo si exite la variable y no está vacía con el condicional `if`.

```
<?php if (isset($email)) {echo "usted ingreso $email";} ?>
```

Answer (score 2):

El resultado de la variable se muestra así por que cuando la página se carga, aún no se le asigna ningún valor a dicha variable.

Si usas PHP 7, puedes hacerlo del modo siguiente:

```
<?php "Usted ingreso: ".$mail ?? "Usted aún no ingresa email alguno"; ?>
```

**Explicación**

- El operador `??` verifica si la variable esta declarada `isset` y no esta vacía `empty`
- El valor del lado izquierdo se imprimirá si la variable tiene valor asignado
- El valor del lado derecho se imprimirá si la variable esta vacía